# How to send&receive parameters in threads using _beginthread method in C++, windows 7

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to perform the operation stated above.

```
void myFunc(void *parameters)
{
   myObject myObj = // Here I would like to receive the object I passed from the main

   ... // several stuff
}

...

int main()
{
   ...
    myObject myObj(...);
   _beginthread(myFunc, // Here I would like to pass on the object I created above)
   ...
}
```

Thanks in advance for your time. Have a pleasent day !

Comment: What have you tried? You posted a question 15 minutes ago regarding the same topic, did you take the time to actually research this yourself?

Comment: I am researching just as I have asked the question, I did this so that perhaps someone will answer it before I figure out myself as I assumed that people here answer the questions because they enjoy doing so. I'm sorry if I offended you.

Comment: That's not how this site works. Do your research first (including searching on this site), ask here when you're stuck and show what you have tried, explaining precisely what is wrong and what you want to do.

Comment: You have `parameters` argument in your source code and it is taken from one of the arguments you pass on to `_beginthread`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly from [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) of `_beginthreadex`:

```
// crt_begthrdex.cpp
// compile with: /MT
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <process.h>

int Counter; 
unsigned __stdcall SecondThreadFunc( void* pArguments )
{
    printf( "In second thread...\n" );

    while ( Counter < 1000000 )
        Counter++;

    _endthreadex( 0 );
    return 0;
} 

int main()
{ 
    HANDLE hThread;
    unsigned threadID;

    printf( "Creating second thread...\n" );

    // Create the second thread.
    hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, &SecondThreadFunc, NULL, 0, &threadID );

    // Wait until second thread terminates. If you comment out the line
    // below, Counter will not be correct because the thread has not
    // terminated, and Counter most likely has not been incremented to
    // 1000000 yet.
    WaitForSingleObject( hThread, INFINITE );
    printf( "Counter should be 1000000; it is-> %d\n", Counter );
    // Destroy the thread object.
    CloseHandle( hThread );
}
```

**UPDATE: How to use the argument without global variables.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <process.h>

using namespace std;

void myFunction( void* arg){

     MyObject myObj = *(MyObject*)arg;

     // do something with your object

     _endthread();

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MyObject myObj(/*...*/);

    _beginthread( myFunction, 0, (void*)&myObj);

    // You can also use the example above for hints on how
    // to wait for the thread to terminate before exiting
    // your application.
    return 0;
}
```

HINT: replace the int with your object

Comment: That doesn't show how to use the argument to the thread procedure.  And using global variables is a horrible way to solve this problem.

Comment: Updated with an example on how to use the argument to the thread procedure without variables.

Comment: Much much better.  Still, copying the object is probably less desirable than binding a reference or pointer.

Comment: in main, can you even create that object on the stack, and pass it to the thread? the updated example defines MyObject on the stack inside main.